# Fread with both skip and select options gets strange results

Tags: r, data.table

For example I have a data table file saved as "t.csv" via following commands:

```
dt <- data.table(A = letters[rep(1:3, 2)],
                 X = 1:6,
                 B = letters[rep(2:4, 2)],
                 Y = 6:1)
fwrite(dt,"t.csv", row.name=F, quote=T)
```

If there is no skip setting, I can read certain columns in any order by provide a vector of column names via "select=". However, if there is a need to skip certain rows, I can't use column name for select, for example, next command will generate error:

```
dt <- fread("t.csv", skip = 1, select = "X")
```

> ```
> # Error in ans[[1L]] : subscript out of bounds
> # In addition: Warning message:
> # In fread("t.csv", skip = 1, select = "X") :
> #   Column name 'X' not found in column name header (case sensitive), skipping.
> ```

It seems that once fread skip a row, it loses all the column names as well, is that true? Anyway, in this case, I have to use column index for select columns. However, here is weird situation: if the column index is NOT an ascending order, the resulted column order is messed up

```
dt <- fread("t.csv", skip = 2, select = c(3, 1, 2))

   V2 V3 V1
1:  2  c  b
2:  3  d  c
3:  4  b  a
4:  5  c  b
5:  6  d  c
```

how to understand this?

Another question is about the secondary index of the data table. Once I `setindex(dt, V3)`, how can I display it in the order of V3?

Thanks.

Comment: You are explicitly telling it to skip 2 rows, which happens to include the row with the header (column names). Though I understand why it could be confusing, another perspective: you are telling it that the first two rows are to be completely discarded, even though you and I believe that one of those rows includes (meta-)data we need. If you want the column headers using `fread(..., skip=2)`, then I suspect you'll need to either (a) assign them manually, or (b) combined it with a call to `fread(..., nrows=2)` to get the column names dynamically.

Comment: The select order issue has been noted before [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1445). Looks like the [latest version of `fread` on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/fread.R) has corrected this issue, though it hasn't cascaded down to the current version on CRAN (1.11.4) yet.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I hope the select order issue would be addressed soon because it has significant impact if user assumes that desired column is chosen but in fact not.

Comment: what about the display/use sorted column based on secondary index?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full column-name in select (V3, V1 and V2):

```
fread( "t.csv", skip = 2, select = paste0( "V", c( 3, 1, 2) ) )
#    V3 V1 V2
# 1:  c  b  2
# 2:  d  c  3
# 3:  b  a  4
# 4:  c  b  5
# 5:  d  c  6
```